# How/Where can i get the script file 'Virtualbox.run'?

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed .deb file (virtualbox-5.2_5.2.8-121009~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb) on uBuntu 16.04, and i tried getting 'Virtualbox.run' (as in the link https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-linux-host) but there aren't any files with that name.

How/Where can I get the script file 'VirtualBox.run'? 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

On the official website:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

There is a downloading option **All distributions (built on EL5 and therefore do not require recent system libraries) ** at the bottom.

More specifically for 64-bit systems the script is here:
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.8/VirtualBox-5.2.8-121009-Linux_amd64.run